# C#: Method signatures?

Tags: c#, method-signature

Let's say I create these two methods:

```
public void AddScriptToPage(params string[] scripts) { /*...*/ }
public void AddScriptToPage(string href, string elementId) { /*...*/ }
```

Which one of these methods gets call by the code below, and why?

```
AddScriptToPage("dork.js", "foobar.js");
```

How does the compiler determine which method to call?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your second method gets called, if an exact match is found, it's used before params.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645765(VS.71).aspx):

When performing overload resolution, a method with a parameter array may be applicable either in its normal form or in its expanded form (Section 7.4.2.1). The expanded form of a method is available only if the normal form of the method is not applicable and only if a method with the same signature as the expanded form is not already declared in the same type.

Their example:

```
using System;
class Test
{
   static void F(params object[] a) {
      Console.WriteLine("F(object[])");
   }
   static void F() {
      Console.WriteLine("F()");
   }
   static void F(object a0, object a1) {
      Console.WriteLine("F(object,object)");
   }
   static void Main() {
      F();
      F(1);
      F(1, 2);
      F(1, 2, 3);
      F(1, 2, 3, 4);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
F();
F(object[]);
F(object,object);
F(object[]);
F(object[]);
```

Comment: This is particularly confusing to people when they call F(null).  Do you get F((object[])null) or F(new object[] { null } ) ?  Many people expect the latter, but since the former is applicable in the normal form, it is better.

Comment: @Eric - You never cease to amaze me with a deep framework question/fact I'd never think of...but end up using in practice months later. Some of your answers here have made tremendous performance differences for me, keep it up.

Comment: Along the lines of your comment, if you haven't read the annotated specification published by Microsoft, you really should; it's a gold mine.

Answer (score 5):

```
public void AddScriptToPage(string href, string elementId)
```

.. will get called. The compiler chooses the signature with the most accurate match, with params having least priority.